# Uniqueness of probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\mathbb{P_1},\mathbb{P_2}$ are two probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ with the same distribution function. Show that $\mathbb{P_1}=\mathbb{P_2}$.
I was thinking of a proof using the principle of good sets as the set $\mathcal{A}=\{A:\mathbb{P_1}(A)=\mathbb{P_2}(A) \}$ is a monotone class. But I can't use the fact that their distributions are same.
Can anybody help?

Comment: "probability distribution" is usually used synonymously with "probability measure". Do you mean the CDF?

Comment: Here the distribution means $\mathbb{P}oX^{-1}$ where $X$ is the random variable concerned

Comment: That is, the RV $X$ maps $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{P_i}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{P}_i o X^{-1})$

Answer (score 1):

Considering $\mathcal{A}=\{A\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\colon\mathbb{P}_1(A)=\mathbb{P}_2(A)\}$ is a good idea. However, I don't think there's a need to invoke something like the Monotone Class Theorem. Note two things:

1. $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
2. You have $\mathbb{P}_1((-\infty,x])=\mathbb{P}_2((-\infty,x])$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(-\infty,b]\setminus(-\infty,a]=(a,b]$ for $a<b$.

Note also that $\mathbb{P_1}=\mathbb{P_2}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. Can you use this to derive the result?

Comment: Yes, I can show $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ , but how can you show the equivalence of showing $\mathbb{P_1}=\mathbb{P_2}$ to showing $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}_1=\mathbb{P_2}\Leftrightarrow\mathbb{P}_1(A)=\mathbb{P}_2(A)\ \forall A\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\Leftrightarrow\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{P_1}(A)=\mathbb{P_1}oX^{-1}$ here? and $\mathbb{P_1}$ as the measure on the domain side?

Comment: I'm not sure what the notation $\mathbb{P}_1oX^{-1}$ is supposed to mean here. A probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ is a map $\mathbb{P}\colon\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\rightarrow[0,1]$ satisfying certain properties. As such, two probability measures $\mathbb{P_1},\mathbb{P_2}\colon\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\rightarrow[0,1]$ are equal iff $\mathbb{P_1}(A)=\mathbb{P_2}(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ (that's simply what it means for two maps to be equal).